# PHP Login Page with Preg_Match Validation

Tags: php

The problem that I am facing is that my Preg_Match validation is not working at all. All I have to do is click the Login Button and it Logs in. I need it to be when the user leaves anything blank or makes an error the validation picks up the error and displays the appropriate error message.

**Here is My Code**

**Index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
?>
<!-- The HTML login form -->
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
    Email:<br> 
    <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    Password:<br> 
    <input type="password" name="password" /><br /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
    <a href="Register.php"/>Sign Up</a>
</form>
<?php
} else {
include("DBConn.php");
mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(!$email)
{
    echo('Enter an email');
}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z\.]+$/i', $email))
{
    echo('Enter a valid email');
}
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{50}$/', $password)) {
    echo 'The password does not meet the requirements!';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE Email LIKE '{$email}' AND Password LIKE     '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$sql);
if (!$result == 1) {
    echo "<p>Invalid email/password combination</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p> Users Email is: $email</p>";
    echo "<p> Users Password is: $password </p>";
    echo "<p> Users Encrypted Password is: '".md5($password)."'</p>";
    echo"<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
?>  
    <a href="Item.php"/>Click here to go to Store.</a>
<?php
}
}
?>      
</body>
</html>
```

**DBConn.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Connect to DB</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
$DBName = "Test";
$DBConnect = mysqli_connect ("127.0.0.1","root","","test");

if($DBConnect === FALSE)
        echo "<p> Connection Failed /<p>\n";

    else {
        echo "<p> Successfully connected to the " . "\"$DBName\" database .        </p>\n";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**CreateTable.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Create Table</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
include("DBConn.php");
$TableName = "tbl_User";
$SQLString = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$TableName'";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$SQLString);
$FileName = 'userData.csv';

if($QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$SQLString))
{
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($QueryResult);
}
if($numRows == 0)
echo "<p> This table does not exist and will be created now. ";
else
{
$SQLString = "DROP TABLE tbl_User";
$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$SQLString);
if($QueryResult === FALSE)
    echo "<p> Table already exsits</p>";
else 
    echo "<p> Successfully deleted the table.</p>";
}
if($numRows == 0)
{
$SQLString = "CREATE TABLE tbl_User (ID SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,FirstName VARCHAR(50),LastName VARCHAR(50),Email  VARCHAR(50),Password VARCHAR(50))";

$QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect , $SQLString);
    if($QueryResult === FALSE)
        echo "<p> Unable to create the tbl_User table. </p>" . "<p> Error Code" .
    mysqli_errno($DBConnect) . ":" . mysqli_error($DBConnect) . "</p>";

    else
        echo "<p> Successfully created the tbl_User table.</p>";
}
if(file_exists($FileName))
{
echo "\nFile Exits";
$twoDarray = array();
if (($handle = fopen("userData.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $twoDarray[] = $data;
}
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r(array_filter($twoDarray[$data]));
echo "</pre>";

foreach($twoDarray as $rows)
{
    $SQLString = "INSERT INTO tbl_User(FirstName,LastName,Email,Password) VALUES ('$rows[0]','$rows[1]','$rows[2]','$rows[3]')";
    $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$SQLString);
}
fclose($handle);
}
else {
echo "\nFile does not exsits, Wrong path";
}
}


?>
```

Comment: The password has to be exactly 50 hex numbers? How did you come up with that?

Comment: In the database that we created it was a length of 50 in phpMyAdmin @mario

Comment: The number you see in `PHPMyAdmin` is a maximum length, not a minimum or exact length.

Comment: To validate your password you can also use `ctype_xdigit()` since it is hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it looks like you are storing plain-text passwords and this is unethical and very insecure.

Secondly, you need to look in using prepared statements (MySQLi or PDO)

Thirdly, to stop the execution of the sql if an error occurs change your ifs to this. By doing so if an error occurs you echo the error and stop the sql execution:

```
if(!$email)
{
    $err_msg = 'Enter an email';
}
elseif(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z\.]+$/i', $email))
{
    $err_msg = 'Enter a valid email';
}
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{50}$/', $password)) {
    $err_msg .= ' The password does not meet the requirements!';
}

if(!empty($err_msg)) {
    echo $err_msg;
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE Email LIKE '{$email}' AND Password LIKE     '{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($DBConnect,$sql);
    if (!$result == 1) {
        echo "<p>Invalid email/password combination</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p> Users Email is: $email</p>";
        echo "<p> Users Password is: $password </p>";
        echo "<p> Users Encrypted Password is: '".md5($password)."'</p>";
        echo"<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
}
?>
```

Fourth: You are checking that there are exactly 50 of `[0-9a-f]` in your pregmatch by doing `/^[0-9a-f]{50}$/` you need to change this to `/^[0-9a-f]{1,50}$/` `{1,50}` means between 1 and 50. This also means a user cannot have any capitals in their password either.

Perhaps you are looking for something along the lines of `(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}` which checks that there is at least 1 number, 1 lower case letter , 1 upper case letter and is 6 characters long minimum.

**edit for prepared statements**

When using MySQLi prepared statements you need to do the following:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if($stmt = $DBConnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
    $stmt->store_result();
    if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
        echo 'success';
    }
    else {
        echo 'failure';
    }
}
else {
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($DBConnect->error));
}
$stmt->close();
```

However when you are dealing with passwords you really should be hashing them using phps hashing ([php](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)) and storing a salt to retrieve also.

Comment: The validation works here but when I try click on Log in it says Invalid email/password combination.

Comment: Your like conditions have no wildcards that probably hinders the query. However please look at prepared statements asap for the security of your database.

Comment: I have added the prepared statements asap above to the main question if that helps.

Comment: @DevAnon i don't see any prepared statements? I have edited my answer with an example of how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Some simpler validations for both the email and password:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
    // Email is valid
}

if (ctype_xdigit($password) && strlen($password) == 50) {
    // Password is valid
}
```